# Renci.SshNet.Common.SshException: 'cipher name aes256-ctr for openssh key file is not supported'

Tags: c#, .net, sftp, ssh.net

When I pass the path of my file, I get the following error:

> Renci.SshNet.Common.SshException: 'cipher name aes256-ctr for openssh
> key file is not supported'

Can anyone help me?

I've tried:

```
var keyFile = new PrivateKeyFile(privateKeyPath);
```

and also:

```
var keyFile = new PrivateKeyFile(privateKeyPath, passphrase);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update to the latest version of SSH.NET (2023.0.1 currently).

It does support the aes256-ctr cipher for OpenSSH private keys.

Comment: I changed it to version 2023.0.1 of the SSH.NET and it worked, thank you very much.